# AppleScript loop to ask (3) questions, select multiple finder files, combine results into a text file

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I am looking for some help getting an apple script setup.  I have been trying to copy and past from different examples on the web to no avail.  I am setting up a journal / diary for a family member and need to have a text file that contains the following information.

The AppleScript will display a dialogue box asking for three things:
    The name of an event
    The date of the event
    A description for the event

Each of those would be stored as a separate variable.

Then the script would ask for a selection of files from the Finder, nothing nested, just a selection of 15 - 30 files all contained in the same folder.

Finally a new TextEdit document would be created 
The beginning of the document would have the (3) variables mixed in with some default text.
The middle of the file would be filled in with a repeat loop based on the number of files selected from the finder.  Their file paths would be mixed in with additional default text.
The last section would be default text only, no variables required.

I am sure my description is way more complicated than the script will probably be.  Would anyone be able to provide this script for me?  It would be most appreciated.

Here is a rough idea what the final thing would look like. The bold areas are the variables.

> The activity of the day was **scuba diving.**
>   The date you went scuba diving was **January 1, 2016**.
>   **This is a description of your event.  The day was quite beautiful and the water was perfect.  You were able to see a wide variety of fishes!**
>
> These are the locations of the files from this event.
>   The first file is **/events/scuba/scuba1.txt**
>   These are the locations of the files from this event.
>   The first file is **/events/scuba/scuba2.txt**
>   These are the locations of the files from this event.
>   The first file is **/events/scuba/scuba3.txt**
>
> This was a summary of your scuba diving activity.  These memories will last a lifetime!

I appreciate the help with this.  And if the family member in question was able to provide a thanks, know that they would as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
set evName to text returned of (display dialog "The name of an event" default answer "")
set evdate to text returned of (display dialog "The date of the event" default answer "")
set evDesc to text returned of (display dialog "A description for the event" default answer "")

set theText to "The activity of the day was " & evName & return & "The date you went " & evName & " was " & evdate & return & evDesc & return & return
set x to choose file with multiple selections allowed

set def1 to "These are the locations of the files from this event."
set def2 to "The first file is "
repeat with i in x
    set theText to theText & def1 & return & def2 & (POSIX path of i) & return
end repeat

set theText to theText & return & "This was a summary of your " & evName & " activity. These memories will last a lifetime!"
tell application "TextEdit"
    make new document with properties {text:theText}
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: That is perfect and exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest an alternative solution using [Evernote](https://evernote.com/)?

You could create a "template" note using a table to fill in the activity, date, and description.  Any time you want a new journal entry, just select the template, and go to Note > Copy to Notebook.

Then you can attach and/or import the text of the files.

This would also allow you to add images and other attachments, and search much easier.  And of course it is easy to share.

Let me know if you'd like more details.

Screenshot of example:
[image]

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion.  There are probably quite a few alternatives for simple journaling.  However this particular situation requires the use of the previously described text file.